# what's the difference between MXML and Actionscript3

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mxml

what's the difference between MXML and Actionscript3
when we need to use MXML ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011587/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-mxml-and-actionscript-3/3011648#3011648

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MXML is a way to design and layout a flex application and Action Script 3 is where all the logic is used.

This of MXML as HTML and ActionScript as Javascript.

Answer (score 6):

When building a flex application, you create and design the visual elements using MXML. Its an XML/HTML style language Of which gives you the ability use a component in a way such as:

```
<progressbar id='progress_bar' />
```

when your flex application compiles itself, this stuff is converted to Actionscript 3.

You don't need to use MXML specifically. It will speed you up and make it super easy to develop you interfaces, but you can still manipulate elements on the stage using actionscript.